# ajax custom dialog box upon success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've coded  a custom dialog/modal box as follows:

```
<div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm a dialog box</h2><
        div><button class="action" data-dialog-close>Close</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is currently triggered by a button with the javascript code as follows:

```
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/dialogFx.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {

        var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog]' ),
            somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
            dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

        dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );

    })();
</script>
```

…where our trigger button has the data-attribute `data-dialog="somedialog"`.

However, now I want to call this custom dialog only when my AJAX returns successful and pass in the message from AJAX into the dialog's `<h2>` text. How do I actually do that?

ajax call:

```
     <script>   
        $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { username: username, password: password},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $self.html("Loading please wait...");
        }
    });

    //WHEN SUCCESS
    request.success(function( data ) {
       if( data == 'user' )
        {
             window.location.href =  "filter.php";
        } else if(data=='company'){
             window.location.href = "filter.php";

        }else {
            alert("Wrong Username or Password!");
             window.location.href = "indexwithlogin.php";

<insert the dialog box here>

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Some questions: (1) Are you going to accept jQuery as a solution? If not, remove the tag. Your question has no jQuery in it, and it's polluting the tag's namespace. (2) Where is the code for your AJAX call?

Comment: yes jquery might be a possible solution

Comment: @isherwood OP revised the question and added jQuery code in it. You can verify that by looking at the timestamps of revision history.

Answer (score 0):

From your first code block you're calling the dialog box using this line:

```
dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
```

...so it is simply the matter of calling it when a success/done response is obtained from the AJAX call. I have made some changes to your script:

- Use the `jqXHR` deferred object `.done()` instead of `.success()`. The latter has been deprecated in favour of `.done()`, and the same for `.error()`, which is succeeded by `.fail()`.
- Convert native JS code into jQuery for the dialog box variable declaration, for consistency — although it's completely ok to use native JS, there is a lack of consistency here
- Remove the window redirection by commenting it out, because it defeats the purpose of displaying the dialog box, no?

Here is the revised JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { username: username, password: password},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $self.html("Loading please wait...");
        }
    });

    // When successful
    // Use deferred object .done()
    request.done(function(data) {
        if(data=='user') {
            window.location.href = "filter.php";
        } else if(data=='company') {
            window.location.href = "filter.php";
        } else {
            alert("Wrong Username or Password!");

            // Call dialogue box
            var dlgtrigger = $('[data-dialog]'),
                somedialog = $(dlgtrigger).attr('data-dialog'),
                dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );

            dlg.toggle.bind(dlg);

            //window.location.href = "indexwithlogin.php";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi then, what about actually passing in the value returned from ajax into the dialog's text

Comment: unfortunately this code doesnt work, an error occured

Comment: @wishfulthinking Not sure if you're username is a pun, but it is really wishful thinking that I know what error you have when you did not provide further information. Please post the error message(s) you get in your browser console. That's a good place to start.

Comment: i did use console log, it didnt return any browser specific errors, just that the pop up doesnt come up

Answer (score 0):

use
`dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)()` inside success function
instead of
`dlg.toggle.bind(dlg)`